# Copy row to Correct tab using Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am using checkbox to copy information in a row to paste it on a different tab with name Alert XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2).  The code I am using is working.

```
Sub Copy_bene()
'
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet, chb As CheckBox
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Name Like "Alert * (Level 2)" Then
    Set wsD = ws: Exit For
   End If
  Next ws
  'wsD.[H2:L6] = ""
 For Each chb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
  If chb.TopLeftCell.Column = 13 And chb = xlOn Then
   Cells(chb.TopLeftCell.row, 8).Resize(, 5).Copy
   wsD.Cells(Rows.count, 8).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlValues
   'Cells(chb.TopLeftCell.Row, 8).Resize(, 5) = "": chb = xlOff
  End If
 Next chb
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My issue is sometimes I will have more tabs with the same name like "Alert 02.15.2020 (Level 2) and Alert XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2) in the same workbook." 
so the code does not paste the information in the correct tab.

How can I change this line `If ws.Name Like "Alert * (Level 2)" Then` so the information will be pasted to the correct tab Alert XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2)?

The name of the sheet where I need the information to be is: **Alert1(Alert XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2) )**

Comment: Why not specify the sheet name then? I don't understand.

Comment: @SJR I guess because it can be _"Alert1(Alert XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2) )"_ also

Comment: @SJR normally the workbook will have this names of the sheets (VBA names):
"Alert (Alert XX.XX.XXXX), Alert1 (Alert XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2)) (here is where I need the information to go).  But sometimes it will have more e.g _Alert(Alert 04.01.2020) (the date will deepens when it was saved), Alert1 (XX.XX.XXXX (Level 2)), Alert2 (Alert 12.02.2020) Alert4 (11.03.2020 (Level 2))_ in this case the information will be pasted in the Alert4 and not Alert1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
If ws.Name Like "*Alert*XXX*(Level 2)*" Then
```